# How to determine the time complexity for the following algorithms (big-Oh notation)?

Tags: java

I am completely new here and what I am fighting with is understanding the Big-oh notation concept. Recently I have started "data structure and algorithm" course in my school and the term Big-oh is very unfamilar to me. I searched a lot online about the topic, but no single explanation satisfied me.
I, however, think that understanding the notation with an example could me much better than just explaining it in plain english.

The following two for loops I got as a practice purpose.
Could you please explain the time complexity of those (in big-oh notation) and also explain explain how it becomes?

(a)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i+=2) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        int temp = i * j;
}
```

(b)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i*=2){
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        int temp = i * j;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Find the total number of times the line `int temp = i*j` executes, as a function of the input parameter `n`. From that function discard everything except the fastest-rising term and also drop any linear coefficient from it. You are only interested in the *kind* of that term (constant, logarithmic, linear, quadratic, *n*-th power, exponential, etc.)

In (a), this will be n<sup>2</sup>. In (b) it will be n*log(n). That is your big-O complexity.

---

As a technical sidenote, the actual time complexity of that code executed on the HotSpot JVM, after Just-in-Time compilation, will be *zero* because the compiler will have no difficulty realizing the code has no effect. It will simply erase it in entirety.

Answer (score 0):

the body of the loop is not very meaningfull, but let's ignore that...

a)

you do (n/2)*n operations. If you know what Oh notation is, it is clear. O(n^2).

b)

you do approximately log2(n)*n operations (you have to double the n to increase number of `i`s processed). O(nlogn).

Do you know, how to get this<

Comment: How it becomes (n/2)*n and log2(n)*n? and finally, No, I dont know how to get this.

Comment: a) The first for cycle goes through each odd i from 1 to n, which causes that the second for cycle is executed n/2 times (the difference when n is even or odd may be ignored). The second for cycle goes from 1 to n, thus it makes n times the counted task. Together it makes (n/2)*n operations = 1/2*n^2; the coefficient may be ignored for the big O notation.

Comment: b) the second for loop is the same as before (n operations per executuion). First loop goes from 1 to n by doubling. If you start with 1 and double the i each time (the kth i will be 2^(k-1)), so the maximum k will be such, that the 2^(k-1)=n => k-1 = log2(n) This will mean, that the second loop will be executed only log2(n) times (if you ignore the 1 for big O).

Comment: V-X, I can grasp the core of it now.